# pass value to popup window [javascript]

Tags: javascript

Have problem with passing value to modal pop up.

This is link to modal edit.

```
 <a href=\"#edit\" data-toggle=\"modal\">
      <button class=\"btn btn-primary image-id-btn\" data-image=$id>edit</button></a>
```

here is code for modal pop up it works fine

```
<!-- MODAL START -->
<div id="edit" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title">edit content</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<<form id="modal-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" action="edited.php" data-remote="true" >
<fieldset>  
<div class="image-id-holder">
<input type="text" value=imageID />
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<input id="modal-form-submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href"#" value="edit"/>
<button class="btn btn-danger"  data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- MODAL END -->
```

My javascript code :

```
<script>
        $(".image-id-btn").on("click", function(){
            var imageId = $(this).attr("data-image");
            $(".image-id-holder").children("input").val(imageId);
        });

</script>
```

The problem is, i can not pass the $id to pop up window, to edit content i am trying to.

thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

theextra < change from

```
<<form id="modal-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" action="edited.php" data-remote="true" >
<fieldset>
```

to

```
<form id="modal-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" action="edited.php" data-remote="true" >
<fieldset>
```

for these code is belongs to jquery

```
$(".image-id-btn").on("click", function(){
    var imageId = $(this).attr("data-image");
    $(".image-id-holder").children("input").val(imageId);
});
```

if you like to use these code, I would like to include jquery js file and wrop these js code into

```
$(function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your js looks fine to me. If this`<input type="text" value=imageID />` is what you have in you code try to changing it to `<input type="text" value="" />` that might be causing your problem.

Comment: this way
`<input type="text" value="imageId"/> `
gives only imageId as string ... not value of imageID

Comment: change `data-image=$id` to `data-image="$id"` and in <input type="text" value="" /> the value should be either empty or undeclared. when constructing an element in HTML all atribute values should be quoted

Comment: Ah i see, i asumed you havent shared the entire code, anyway glad to help